# Что будет выведено в консоль?

Tags: javascript

Коллеги, всем привет.
Не понимаю, почему в консоль будет выведено man, undefined?

```js
var a = 'hello';

function b() {
  if (false) {
    var a = 'world';
  } else {
    var b = 'man';
  }
  console.log(b);
  console.log(a);
}
b();
```

По-поводу вывода значения переменной b = man мне понятно, а вот почему переменная а будет неопределена, не понимаю. В моем понимании а должно быть равно hello, т.к. при вызове функции b() значение переменной а должно взяться из внешней переменной, разве не так?

Comment: Не зная JS сразу предположу, что `a` = `undefined`, т.к. блок `var a = "hello";` не был затронут, соответственно переменной этой нет, что логично, по крайней мере в C# изначально идет проверка на наличие переменной в текущем scope, а потом уже снаружи (в классе, например), что подтверждается, если написать не `console.log(a)`, а `console.log(this.a)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Правильно**:
man
undefined

*Почему?*

1. Переменная `a` объявлена и имеет значение `hello`.
2. В блоке `else` функции `b()` переменной `b` присваивается значение `man` (Поэтому и выводится это значение)
3. Поскольку переменная `a` в блоке `if` не переопределяется (условие `if (false)` *не выполняется*), `console.log(a)` выведет `undefined`, так как переменная `a` из блока `if` не имеет отношения к переменной `a` из внешней области видимости функции `b`.

Т.е необходимо убрать создание переменной  `var a='world';`, а сделать присваивание уже существующей глобальной переменной `a='world';`.

Comment: Спасибо. А в каком  случае условие if (false) может быть выполнено?

Comment: @ghost3ds, `if (false)` никогда не выполнится